# Android log main events radio buffers

Tags: android, android-logcat

I've downloaded offline logcat tool.
It syncs between  log(main/events/radio) buffers but I don't know what are those buffers.
Will be glad to get some references.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**main** - the main application log
**events** - for system event information
**radio** - for radio and phone-related informatio
**system** - a log for low-level system messages and debugging

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here the answer, just 4 kinds of log messages :)
http://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System